Tag Synonyms page's score tooltip appears in wrong place
On the Tag Synonyms page, when hovering over the number of votes, the tooltip is appearing to the left of the page's title, not underneath the score.
I am using Windows 11, Firefox 133. I do have user scripts, however, I disabled all of these and tested again before posting (the tooltip was actually appearing half off the screen initially, due to my "Stack Overflow full width" script).
In the below image, my cursor is actually over the "2" adjacent to azure-synapse-analytics.

Here is an animated gif as well, to demonstrate it appearing in the wrong place for all scores:

